# Android Studio Emulator vs real Device screen resolution

Tags: android, android-emulator

today I noticed something wired. I have got an Emulator Device running a resolution of 1440x2560. I was developing most of the time on this Emu Device and today I plugged in my cousins Galaxy S7 Edge, which has the same resolution, but I noticed that there was less screen space LOL I know it sounds stupid, but I know for sure because my Admob Ads weren't showing up anymore, and I saw that they didnt have enough space (width,height) to show up. After changing some width & heights settings inside my code the Ads did show up again, but this had me seriously confused. How could this even be possible? The Emu Device has the exact same screen resolution, the same Android Version (Marshmallow). Why would I have more space inside the emulator and less on a real device? Anyone noticed something familiar?

Comment: Density != resolution

Comment: @cricket_007 you suggest that it has something to do with the density? the Emu Device has 560 dpi next to its resolution ( I cant change this) whereas the Galaxy has 577 ppi pixel density.. Dont know why its dpi inside the emu and ppi on the phone but I thought it was the same density. Is it possible to set the density inside Android Studio?

Comment: It's not IDE or Android Studio related. The device or emulator controls that. For example, if you root the device, you can change the density. I don't think it's directly configurable otherwise. But if your ads don't display, that's an XML layout issue with your own code, most likely

Comment: I think your layouts break very easily, it's possible to gurantee that stuff shows up on the screen with proper layouts.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful i had to resize some elements in height regarding to the devices screen size measures, in order to show the Ad Banners. its actually a pain in the ass because I have to tweak the height values or else there the Ads dont show up, since they dont get enough space to do so. And I didnt find a way to get it dynamically done.